# ExtJS 4, keypress event on container

Tags: events, extjs4, keypress

I'm using ExtJS 4.1 MVC and I need to perform some actions after user click Enter button.

I did it this way:

```
Ext.getDoc().on('keypress', function(event, target) {
    me._enterKeyHandler(event, target, me);
});
```

But I wonder if somehow I can use [Ext.util.KeyMap](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.KeyMap) in Container. In Sencha docs I found something and tried, but it didn't work for me.

```
var map = new Ext.util.KeyMap({
  // in target I tried: Ext.getCmp('myComponent'), "myComponent", myComponentVar
  target: "my-element",
  key: Ext.EventObject.ENTER,
  fn: function() {alert('enter')}
});
```

So, how how can I listen to keyPress event bot using 'document' ? Help me, please

Answer (score 1):

Ext.util.KeyNav works for me. For example, in a panel:

```
afterRender: function () {
    this.callParent(arguments);

    this.keyNav = Ext.create('Ext.util.KeyNav', this.el, {
        enter: this.onSubmitButton,
        scope: this
    });
}
```

This binds the "Enter" key to the onSubmitButton function in the panel.

Comment: I tried `xtype: "panel",
                id: "faqsViewTopInfoMessage",
                listeners: {
                    afterRender: function () {
                        this.keyNav = Ext.create('Ext.util.KeyNav', this.el, {
                            left : function(e){ alert('left'); },
                            enter: function(){alert('e')},
                            scope: this
                        });
                        // this.callParent(arguments);
                    }
                },
` . It didn't work for me