# Extjs:How to disable enter key event on a button when focused

Tags: extjs

I have a form with a lot of fields, and the users want use ENTER key instead of TAB key to change focus between fields, I have solved textfield/checkbox/combo, but when a button grab focus, ENTER key trigger the click event. How can I disable this ENTER key event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21239698/extjs-4-keypress-event-on-container), It's work for me

```
afterRender: function () {
    this.keyNav = Ext.create('Ext.util.KeyNav', this.el, {
        enter: Ext.getCmp('nextComponentId').focus(),
        scope: this
    });
}
```